# Web Scraper keeps repeating first page instead of multiple pages

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, pagination

I've got this web scraper that I've been trying to work on and perfect. I've asked help already with something else about this code but this time I haven't found anything helpful for this problem yet.

I've been trying to rebuild the code according to some tutorials on the web but doesn't work that much, I am on the verge of starting something else since don't wanna waste too much time if this isn't gonna work.

```
my_url = "https://www.vuokraovi.com/vuokra-asunnot/Uusimaa"
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")


lastpage = int(pages[0].findAll("li")[7].text)

pages = list(range(1, int(lastpage) + 1))
for page in pages:
    my_url = "https://www.vuokraovi.com/vuokra-asunnot/Uusimaa?page=%s&pageType=" %(page)
    containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class":"list-item-container"})

    print("Processing page: %s" %(page))

    for container in containers:
        try:
            Vuokranantaja = container.findAll("div", {"class":"hidden-xs col-sm-3 col-4"})[0].img["alt"]
        except TypeError:
            Vuokranantaja = container.findAll("div", {"class":"hidden-xs col-sm-3 col-4"})[0].p.strong.text.strip()
        except KeyError:
            Vuokranantaja = container.findAll("div", {"class":"hidden-xs col-sm-3 col-4"})[0].a["href"]


        Huoneistot = container.findAll("li", {"class":"semi-bold"})[1].text

        Talotyyppi = container.findAll("li", {"class":"semi-bold"})[0].text

        Sijainti = container.findAll("div", {"class":"hidden-xs col-sm-4 col-3"})[0].findAll("span", {"class":"address"})[0].text.strip().replace("\r", "").replace("\n", "").replace(" ", "").replace(",", ", ")
        try:
            Vapautuu = container.findAll("div", {"class":"hidden-xs col-sm-4 col-3"})[0].findAll("span", {"class":"showing-lease-container hidden-xs"})[0].li.text
        except AttributeError:
            Vapautuu = "Ei Tiedossa"
        Vuokra = container.findAll("li", {"class":"rent"})[0].text.strip()

        print("Kohdetta Vuokraa:", Vuokranantaja)
        print("Huoneistot:", Huoneistot)
        print("Talotyyppi ja Koko:", Talotyyppi)
        print("Sijainti:", Sijainti)
        print("Vapautuu:", Vapautuu)
        print("Vuokra:", Vuokra)
        print("")

        count += 1
        f.write(Vuokranantaja.replace(",", " |") + "," + Huoneistot.replace(",", " - ") + "," + Talotyyppi.replace(",", ".") + "," + Sijainti.replace(",", " -") + "," + Vapautuu + "," + Vuokra.replace(",", ".") + "\n")

f.close()
```

The desired output would be for the code to scrape like it does but on multiple pages, yet it scrapes only on the first page for the amount of times that lastpage equals to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there's a pretty obvious error in your loop, you don't update the content of the page_soup variable at each iteration.

Should be:

```
for page in pages:
    my_url = "https://www.vuokraovi.com/vuokra-asunnot/Uusimaa?page=%s&pageType=" %(page)

    uClient = uReq(my_url)
    page_html = uClient.read()
    page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

    ...
```

Comment: Got it to work now, but it still repeats the first page twice, any ideas how to fix that aswell, and thank you for your time.